# Add several text files into one text file using Mathematica

Tags: export, import, text

I have twenty data files each contains 1000 lines ("a1.txt, a2.txt....a20.txt"). Now I want to add all these files to a single file and keep the line sequence as followed by the input files (first 1000 from a1.txt, next 1000 from a2.txt and so on).
How can I do that?

Comment: Hi Xavier and welcome! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3). [Edit](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: There are **[things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. Participation is essential for the site, please do your part.

Comment: Oh Yes. I am learning Mathematica for data analysis (in Windows)

Comment: I pointed out an issue to the answer you accepted. Can you comment if that's a problem or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A: Do you need to do this in Mathematica? You can just use the shell command `cat` in Unix / Mac OS. (This question is the reverse of the question ["Splitting a text file into smaller text files by line numbers using Mathematica"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/175862/34008), which I answered yesterday.)
>
> X: I am learning Mathematica for data analysis (in Windows)

### Direct commands

Unix paths are used below -- it is better to construct the file names with [`FileNameJoin`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FileNameJoin.html) for OS-independent behavior.

```
fnames = FileNames["~/Downloads/a*.txt"];    
texts = Import /@ fnames;    
Export["~/Downloads/allInOne.txt", StringRiffle[texts, "\n"], "Text"]
```

### Unix / Mac OS

Mentioning this for completeness...

In Unix / Mac OS we can use the command `cat`. From within Mathematica we can make this call:

```
Run["cat ~/Downloads/a*.txt > ~/Downloads/allInOne.txt"]
```

Comment: Thanks Anton! Nice solution.

Comment: Ok great, good luck!

Comment: +1 For cat - I did the very same thing just a few days ago. Much simpler than using mathematica

Comment: @PerAlexandersson Yeah, often enough a Unix commands one-liner is a good alternative to data analysis analysis scripts with other languages/systems. Here is an example, ["Command-line Tools can be 235x Faster than your Hadoop Cluster"](https://adamdrake.com/command-line-tools-can-be-235x-faster-than-your-hadoop-cluster.html).

Comment: Your solution has the problem that it'a not keeping the order of the files, contrary to the OP's request to *" keep the line sequence as followed by the input files"*.   You `fnames ` gives `{"a10.txt", "a11.txt", "a12.txt", "a13.txt", "a14.txt", "a15.txt","a16.txt", "a17.txt", "a18.txt", "a19.txt", "a1.txt", "a20.txt", "a2.txt", "a3.txt", "a4.txt", "a5.txt", "a6.txt", "a7.txt", "a8.txt", "a9.txt"}. Presumably the `cat` solution suffers from the same?

Comment: @rhermans Well, I did say that using `FileNameJojn` is a better option...

Comment: The above solution will be working nicely with a slight modification of the file names:  a01.txt, a02.txt,.........a09.txt, a10.txt.....................

Answer (score 3):

### [`OpenRead`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OpenRead.html) [`OpenWrite`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OpenWrite.html) [`ReadString`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReadString.html)[`WriteString`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WriteString.html)

```
Module[
 {
  newfilename = "all.txt",
  wfile, rfile, str
  },
 wfile = OpenWrite[newfilename];
 Table[
  rfile = OpenRead[StringTemplate["File``.txt"][k]];
  str = ReadString[rfile];
  Close[rfile];
  WriteString[wfile, str];
  , {k, 1, 20}
  ];
 Close[newfilename]
 ]
```

---

### [`Import`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html) and [`Export`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html)

```
Export[
 "All2.txt",
 StringJoin@Table[
   Import[StringTemplate["File``.txt"][k], "String"]
   , {k, 1, 20}
   ]
 , "String"
 ]
```

---

To test my answers I created some files like this

```
SystemOpen@SetDirectory[$TemporaryDirectory]

Array[
  Export[StringTemplate["File``.txt"][#], (# 1000 + Range[1000]), 
    "CSV"] &
  , 20
  ];

Range[1001, 21000] == Flatten@Import["All.txt", "Table"]
(* True *)

Range[1001, 21000] == Flatten@Import["All2.txt", "Table"]
(* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks rhermans...I am working on it